# How to create different variations of my plank?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, node-editor, geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

I've created a plank and the goal is to create a wooden floor. Is there a way to make the pattern on my plank different when I duplicate it? Is there a way to do this without sculpting a whole different plank?

I tried using a texture coordinate and mapping node but I'm not getting the results I'd like. Picture below has an array modifier added.

File: https://we.tl/t-SKUbub2fDU
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use Object Info for Material Variation

Here is a quick solution to achieve some floorboard variation that does not involve further sculpting.

Make linked copies of the plank (apply your *Shrinkwrap Modifier* first). To make a linked copy use `Alt + D` or `option + D`. This will give you more flexibility than using an *Array Modifier*.

Rotate and stagger the planks to get some variation in pattern.

In the Shader Editor, use the *Random* output of an *Object Info Node* To add some variation to the material for each plank.

[image]

Here I'm using the random value from from the *Object Info Node* to randomly brighten or darken the source map for the base color. I also overlay the random value for extra variation.

Here's an exaggerated version so you can see clearly what is being done.

[image]

Comment: Also replacing the texture with a procedural one will allow to change the pattern of wood slightly based on the same Object Info: Random - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation!